# Java Hibernate exception MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have hibernate entity and when I try insert it into MySQL database I get exception:

```
@Entity
public class Pick {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int pid;

@OneToOne
private Match_soccer match;

@OneToOne
private Algo1 algo;

@Column(length = 100)
private String pick;

@Column(length = 5)
private double limit;
...
```

And when I try insert to MySQL database using hibernate:

```
Pick pick = new Pick();
pick.setMatch(match);
pick.setAlgo(a);
pick.setLimit(2.5);
pick.setPick("under");

PickDAO pd = new PickDAO();
pd.insertMatch(pick);
```

I get MySQL exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit, match_mid, pick) values (1, 2.5, 9358, 'under')' at line 1
```

Comment: Did you try changing variable name `limit` to some other ?

Comment: Can you show insertMatch method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Limit` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html). Rename the entity attribute to something else

Comment: This is what I'm guessing :) +1.

Comment: Yes, here was my problem :)

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a bug in the hibernate dialect for mysql.  It's perfectly possible to have a column or table whose name is a reserved word, you just have to quote it properly.  The dialect should be smart enough to take care of that for you.